# Restarting a Docker container with an updated image, from within the running container

Tags: python, docker, sdk, containers, restart

I have the following requirement and I can't seem to get the functionality I'm looking for.

1. I have a Docker container that runs a Python application, let's call the image used to create the container version 1.0.1.
2. A container based on the image is launched from a shell script with the --restart=always option set. I use the image tagged as latest when starting the container. This container runs fine.
3. If I press Alt-F4 while the container is running, the container is closed and is restarted as expected.
4. From within the application, running in a container based on the 1.0.1 image, I am using the Docker SDk for Python to pull a new image down from DockerHub. In the Python code I set the new image, let's call it 1.0.2, to latest and restart the image, using client.containers.get("mycontainername").restart().

The part of this that works is that the code I have pulls the new image from DockerHub and is tagged as latest locally. The running container stops and when I examine the images, the new image is there, 1.0.2, and there is a latest image with the same ID.

The part that isn't working is that the container doesn't restart. The container shuts down, but never restarts as with the Alt-F4.

I have also tried stopping the running container in the code, in place of the restart, and the container stops and doesn't re-start. I'm using client.containers.get("mycontainername").stop() to accomplish this.

Observations:

1. If I restart the shell script, the previous container runs, even though the script file runs the image with the latest tag.
2. The running container is still based on the previous image, 1.0.1.
3. If I reboot the system, the new and correct image, 1.0.2, is used to create the container.

My question is this:

How do I update a running container, from a Python script running in that container, with a new image and restart a container based on the new image?

Comment: *From within the application, running in a container based on the 1.0.1 image, I am using the Docker SDk for Python to pull a new image down from DockerHub.* why would you want to do this?

Comment: You can't do this without having administrator-level permission on the host system (and the operator granting that permission to your container).  I'd let the operator decide if and when to update, doing something like updating an `image:` tag in a Compose file.

Comment: If you did have permission to the Docker socket (and the ability to edit any file on the host system as root), then you'd have to do something like start the new container, verify that it actually came up, change your own restart policy to not restart, and exit cleanly.  "Update a running container" in general isn't a Docker operation, you can only create new containers from different images.